# how can I token words in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I've already defined the token in the tokenizer. so For the tokenizer, it means to take the lexeme and tokens. for example, lexeme a token is id. lexeme = token is equal_sign. So if I type "?- tokenizer("a = a", T)." it will return T= id equal_sign id. if "?- tokenizer("a = 1 + 2", T)." it will return T= id equal_sign 1 add_op 2. However,for my code it can just check one lexeme, I believe that there are something wrong with my recursion. But I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
tokenizer(X, Y) :- token(X, Y).
tokenizer([], []).
tokenizer([H|T], [RH|RT]) :- 
token(H, RH),
tokenizer(T,RT).
tokenizer([_|T],[_|RT]):-
tokenizer(T,RT).
```

Comment: The problem is probably that your input is not a list. In Sictus, if you use double quotes, it will be a list of characters, which is probably not what you wanted. In other Prologs I believe string is an atomic type. There is something wrong with your recursion also. You should not have two recursive clauses. Is the purpose of the second one to skip undefined tokens? Then why do you add the anonymous variable on the output side also? Try to explain what you are trying to do to get better help.